# How to use jQuery's dblclick to open a video from image

Tags: jquery

I'm just getting started with jQuery and decided to try opening a video to the same window by doubleclicking a picture but ran into problems. I found some examples of dblclick showing the hidden p elements but couldn't really convert that into my project. Basically I can't get dblclick to work with this code and most likely I am in need of two div elements but can't really figure out how to put them in this. Thank you in advance.

Code as it is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery doubleclick</title>
        <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="click.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://img.ifcdn.com/images/3b10c8e09263402758a14321e6999b6aa9daac4c8f10c78defd8884fc832d1a7_3.jpg" width="360px" height="240px" id="image"/>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNvDUO42Hys" width="640px" height="480px" id="video"</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image').dblclick(function() {
        $('#video').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sure that we can help you with your problem, but first, could you say exactly what your error is? Please update your post with that info.

Comment: if click.js is reqiured for what you are tring to achieve, then provide that file too.

Comment: @Atula JS code showing there (including .dblclick and .show) is the only thing click.js has in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will wok.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery doubleclick</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img  src="http://img.ifcdn.com/images/3b10c8e09263402758a14321e6999b6aa9daac4c8f10c78defd8884fc832d1a7_3.jpg" width="360px" height="240px" id="image"/>
<iframe width="560" height="315" id='video' style="display:none" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SNvDUO42Hys" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#image').dblclick(function() {
            $('#image').hide();
            $('#video').show();
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: it's worthy to be the **answer**.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks alot! I did put autoplay to video and now it starts playing before I have even doubleclicked the image. Is there any way to start playing the video immediately after doubleclicking the image?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? I removed the `click.js` because I did not have that file and could not include it.
Oh and also, since your `<a>` tag didn't have any text, it would have stayed hidden, so I gave it a little text.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#image').dblclick(function() {
    $("#video").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#video {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://img.ifcdn.com/images/3b10c8e09263402758a14321e6999b6aa9daac4c8f10c78defd8884fc832d1a7_3.jpg" width="360px" height="240px" id="image" />
<div id="video"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNvDUO42Hys">Click for the video!</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I think I know what you are trying to achieve. By double clicking the image, you want to redirect to the video in the same window.

If you want to achieve this by a single click, just wrap the image in an `<a>` tag and set the `href` attribute to the URL. You could include the `target` attribute and set it to `_blank` to open the video in a new window.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNvDUO42Hys">
  <img src="http://img.ifcdn.com/images/3b10c8e09263402758a14321e6999b6aa9daac4c8f10c78defd8884fc832d1a7_3.jpg" width="360px" height="240px" id="image" />
  </a>
```

Or you could do it by doubleclicking for which you will need some code.

```js
$("#image").dblclick(function() {
  window.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNvDUO42Hys";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://img.ifcdn.com/images/3b10c8e09263402758a14321e6999b6aa9daac4c8f10c78defd8884fc832d1a7_3.jpg" width="360px" height="240px" id="image" />
```

Since StackOverflow doesn't allow redirects, the snippets won't show a live example, but try it on your local system.

Comment: Sorry, I explained it poorly but I meant that video basically replaces image after doubleclicking it and it is just a bit bigger than image itself. Also forgot to say in first message that it would be cool to have autoplay on video. (not when image is on the screen but immediately after doubleclicking it)